# How to improve this analog interface for only counting pulses through audio port

Tags: audio, analog, pulse

I want to count pulses through sound-card of a PC or a smartphone's audio port.
Two different pulses will originate from two LM331 and I can scale them to 1V or any amplitude.

I want to feed these pulses to the audio port of a sound card's channels. Then the rest is to software to count the pulses.

So far I plan to use this analog interface between the pulses and the audio jack and sound-card:

[image]

Do you think the topology is correct? How can I improve this interface for the noise? I am only interested to count pulses not to view any other signal.

**Edit:**
R1 R2 sets the voltage at X.

[image]

Comment: This question would be much better if you explained why you chose to design it like this.

Comment: And the frequency of these pulses is ???

Comment: @JImDearden Frequency of the pulses can be set from 100Hz upto 10kHz or more by LM331. I can adjust the freq. I mean. So lets call it "f" if you have an idea.

Comment: The reason I asked was if the frequency is in the audio band (as you've indicated) - no problem, if it was a very low frequency such as 0.1Hz then you'll need a different technique to get the pulse into an audio card.

Comment: @JImDearden How about if it were a smart phone audio jack instead of a soundcard? Can I use the same interface?

Comment: Should be fine, sound cards usually have a low frequency cut off at about 20Hz so 'audio' signals between 20Hz and 20kHz should be catered for.

Comment: @JImDearden Pulse amplitude to the mic should not exceed ±10 mV ? Maybe mine is exceeding the limits?

Answer (score 2):

Check what the input impedance of the sound card is.  It may be that the signal will get significantly attenuated by the 22 kΩ in series.  A common input impedance for "line" inputs is 600 Ω, for example.

I'd start with 1 kΩ in series followed by just two back to back diodes to ground.  ±700 mV is still a substantial signal for line level audio, and totally overwhelming for a microphone input.

If you only have a microphone input, then add another resistor divider after the clipping diodes.  ±10 mV is a strong microphone signal.

Comment: Should I match the series resistor to the input impedance of the soundcard? Is that something to do with max power transfer?

Comment: I edited my question regarding your answer. Please see my edit. Was that you suggested? And the voltage at X should not exceed 10mV(pulse amplitude in my case) right?.

Comment: @user: The diodes should be parallel, not series.

Comment: I see thanks, I changed that. Hopefully makes sense now.